# Iframe pages on Facebook does not show in Internet Explorer 9 - Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-9, facebook

Have this very irritating problem with Internet Explorer 9 and Facebook.

If I go to Facebook and watch a page with iframes (like IFBML pages) it will not show up in Internet Explorer 9. 
It shows up in Firefox 4 and Chrome 10, but not in Internet Explorer 9.

I run Windows 7 64-bit SP1 (danish). The strange thing is that I own three different PC´s and they all run Windows 64-bit SP1 and all of them has this issue. Can´t figure out what causes this issue.

I have tried the following:

1. Uninstalled AVG antivirus and installed Microsoft Antivirus - no change
2. Updated Windows with SP1 - no change
3. Updated from Internet Explorer 9 beta to Internet Explorer 9 final Ed. - no change
4. Emptied cache and temp files in Internet Explorer 9 - no change
5. Made www.facebook.com a trusted site in Internet Explorer 9 - no change

And a lot of other things I can not remember I guess....but nothing seems to work.

As I´m using quite a lot of my working time developing Facebook Fanpages it is frustrating not to be able to test them in Internet Explorer 9.

BTW - it is Internet Explorer 9 32-bit - not 64-bit.

Any clues?

Comment: Solution: Stop using Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the 64-bit version of Internet Explorer 9 on the start menu. I had a lot of problems with Facebook if I simply opened Internet Explorer from the icon in the Quick Launch bar. I had no problems when using the 64-bit version of Internet Explorer 9.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer sometimes have compatibility issues with websites. I do not know, whether is that the problem which causes for you as well.

As per **Microsoft Support**, if a site is incompatible, a small icon will appear infront of the address bar notifying that the site is incompatible. Simply click on that icon to make it compatible.

Please visit **[here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/use-compatibility-view#ie=ie-10)** for more info.